# Checking what type of character the unicode character is

Tags: c#, if-statement, unicode, char

I am running through CodeEasy.net's c# program and I have stumbled across a problem I am struggling with. I don't understand why this does not pass.

> Write a program that reads from the console one char using
>   Console.Read() and Convert.ToChar(...) methods. After this, the
>   program should output "Digit" "Letter" or "Not a digit and not a
>   letter" to the screen, depending on what the character is.

I have tried int `charCode = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` as well instead of `int charCode = Console.Read();` but nothing seems to work. It keeps giving me the first "if" and last "else" result, but only one of these should print so it is very confusing.

Here is my code so far:

```
int charCode = Console.Read();
char theRealChar = Convert.ToChar(charCode);

if (char.IsDigit(theRealChar))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digit");
}
if (char.IsLetter(theRealChar))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Letter");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a digit and not a letter");
}
```

Any help in making me understand this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` statement is *only* associated with the second `if` statement. You've effectively got:

```
if (firstCondition)
{
    // Stuff
}

// You could have unrelated code here

if (secondCondition)
{
    // Stuff
}
else
{
    // This will execute any time secondCondition isn't true, regardless of firstCondition
}
```

If you only want it to execute if *neither* of the earlier `if` statements, you need the second one to be `else if`:

```
if (char.IsDigit(theRealChar))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digit");
}
// Only check this if the first condition isn't met
else if (char.IsLetter(theRealChar))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Letter");
}
// Only execute this at all if neither of the above conditions is met
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a digit and not a letter");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This really cleared things up for me :) I was unaware I had to use "else if".

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine once you add a missing `else` before the second `if` block.

```
if (char.IsDigit(theRealChar))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digit");
}
else if (char.IsLetter(theRealChar))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Letter");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a digit and not a letter");
}
```